# How to download signed document using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

Please share docusign API to download signed document. Request body.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/ has this in 8 different coding languages.

the request is a GET call, so the request body is not needed (empty).

You make a GET call to this endpoint:

{base_path}/v2.1/accounts/${account_id}/envelopes/${envelope_id}/documents/${doc_choice}

You will need your:

1. base_path - in the developer account it would be https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/
2. account_id - your accountId for the account that was used to create the envelope
3. envelope_id - your envelopeId for the envelope sent for signing.
4. doc_choice - your documentId or if you want to get a ZIP file, combined or PDF portfolio.